# Database mnemonics

Tags: database, transactions, mnemonics, relational-model

I'm looking for mnemonics to help me with databases, the relational model and transaction theory. For example I learned "ACID" to help me remember the properties of a transaction: atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability. What others are out there?

Comment: This should be community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

CRUD - Create/Read/Update/Delete, the four basic DB operations.

Answer (score 2):

To remember the first three normal forms:

> The key, the whole key, and nothing
>   but the key.

Answer (score 0):

Just for giggles:

I'll curse you, if you use a cursor

Comment: Depends on how the cursor is used. Not all cursors are bad. There's this rad one from pre-2000 Windows called Dinosaur...